# How to properly reencode videos for YouTube shorts with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video, youtube

I have tried many encoding and everytime YouTube app is saying unable to preview video when I try to upload my video as YouTube shorts

The app is able to see tiktok generated output file, however I don't want to use it for obvious quality and watermark reasons

So what command would convert video into YouTube short supported format with keeping best possible quality

Comment: Does [FFMPEG wiki Encode/YouTube](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube) answer the question?

Comment: @harrymc it doesnt work. however I made it work with handbrake somehow. their shorts uploading system is so broken actually